# Issue with systemd-networkd not assigning a static IP if network device is not plugged in at boot time

Tags: systemd, ip, systemd-networkd

I have a linux embedded system built using Buildroot, it has systemd v250.

On a previous builtroot version, it was using systemd v232.

I have the following network file defined:

*/etc/systemd/network/20-wired.network*

```
[Match]
Name=usb0

[Network]
Address=192.168.89.14/24
```

This configuration was working fine on my older buildroot image, right after boot when I checked the ip address :

```
# ip a

3: usb0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 36:f9:b3:30:8f:b8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.90.14/24 brd 192.168.90.255 scope global usb0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

But now, using a newer buildroot, I cannot get the IP address to be assigned at boot time:

```
# ip a

3: usb0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 4a:1d:3c:df:39:ea brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

When I try to check what is happening using networkctl, I have the following output:

```
● 3: usb0                   
                 Link File: /usr/lib/systemd/network/99-default.link
              Network File: /etc/systemd/network/20-wired.network
                      Type: gadget
                     State: no-carrier (configuring)
              Online state: offline
                      Path: platform-ci_hdrc.0
                    Driver: g_ether
          Hardware Address: 4a:1d:3c:df:39:ea
                       MTU: 1500
                     QDisc: pfifo_fast
  Number of Queues (Tx/Rx): 1/1
         Activation Policy: up
       Required For Online: yes

Oct 04 16:48:16 rpi systemd-networkd[229]: usb0: Requesting static route (n/a): dst: n/a, src: n/a, gw: 192.168.89.1, prefsrc: n/a, scope: global, table: main(254), proto: static, type: unicast, nexthop: 0, prioa
Oct 04 16:48:16 rpi systemd-networkd[229]: usb0: Requesting routes
Oct 04 16:48:16 rpi systemd-networkd[229]: usb0: link_check_ready(): link layer is configuring.
Oct 04 16:48:16 rpi systemd-networkd[229]: usb0: Setting master interface
Oct 04 16:48:16 rpi systemd-networkd[229]: usb0: master interface set.
Oct 04 16:48:16 rpi systemd-networkd[229]: usb0: link_check_ready(): link is not activated.
Oct 04 16:48:16 rpi systemd-networkd[229]: usb0: Bringing link up
Oct 04 16:48:16 rpi systemd-networkd[229]: usb0: Flags change: +UP
Oct 04 16:48:16 rpi systemd-networkd[229]: usb0: Link UP
Oct 04 16:48:16 rpi systemd-networkd[229]: usb0: link_check_ready(): static addresses are not configured.
```

I am not quite sure what is going wrong here and how to fix this, does anyone have an idea ?

I thank you in advance for your help.

Regards,

Azsde.